# For any given matrix Is there exist some polynomial which can convert that into required one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I wanted to check following possibility .
I have $$
A=\left  [\begin{matrix}
 a  & b \\
c & d\\
\end{matrix} \right] 
$$ Now I wanted to find Polynomial such that
 
$$
f(A)=\left  [\begin{matrix}
 0  & -1 \\
1 & 0\\
\end{matrix} \right] $$.
Is this always possible?
I had done some calculatution but I did not get.
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: If $A$ is the zero matrix, then $f(A)$ will just be the constant term of $f$, which must be a scalar matrix. So in this case, it is impossible.

Comment: It is easy to see that $f(A)$ and $A$ commute. You only need a matrix that does not commute with $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and you have a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fact that $f(A)$ and $A$ commute, we conclude that $A$ must commute with $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$ This in turn results in the requirements $a=d$ and $b=-c.$ If $b=c=0,$ then $f(A)$ would only be a multiple of the identity matrix. Therefore, we can also conclude $b=-c\neq 0.$ Now it is easy to find our polynomial:
$$
f(x) = \frac xc - \frac ac
$$